# Chromecast Cast Hello World App does not run with my application id

Tags: android, https, connection, chromecast, app-id

When I copy the Chromecast Cast Hello World App (provided with the SDK) in an Eclipse project with different package name (I name it MY PACKAGE here) it runs perfectly. But as soon as I use the app_id created under the Google Cast SDK Developer Console (I name it MY APPLICATION ID here) it does not run anymore.

In the Google Cast SDK Developer Console I choose “Android” as the platform, provide the package name MY PACKAGE and an https address "https://SOME_WEB_ADDRESS.html" which refers to a web page containing the following (copied from https://github.com/pjjanak/chromecast-hello-world):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/receiver.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="messages">
        <h1>Waiting for Messages...</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/cast/js/receiver/1.0/cast_receiver.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="messageTypes.js"></script> can be removed -->
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var receiver = new cast.receiver.Receiver('<MY APPLICATION ID>', ['urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.helloworld']),
            channelHandler = new cast.receiver.ChannelHandler('urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.helloworld'),
            $messages = $('.messages');

            channelHandler.addChannelFactory(
            receiver.createChannelFactory('urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.helloworld'));

            receiver.start();

            channelHandler.addEventListener(cast.receiver.Channel.EventType.MESSAGE, onMessage.bind(this));

            function onMessage(event) {
                $messages.html(event.message.type);
            }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

If I call open web page https://SOME_WEB_ADDRESS.html responses with “Waiting for Messages...”.

The application with ID “MY APPLICATION ID” is not yet published under the Google Cast SDK Developer Console, nor has it been uploaded to the Google play Developer Console.

When running the app with MY APPLICATION ID the Chromecast symbol in the action bar is displayed.

When I connect my device the screen attached to my Chromecast device turns black, but I get the following error in class ConnectionCallbacks (else branch with comment “Launch the receiver app”):
05-12 19:56:59.950: D/MainActivity(12523): ApplicationConnectionResultCallback.onResult: statusCode 15

The result with the original app_id is:
05-12 19:53:49.727: D/MainActivity(11778): ApplicationConnectionResultCallback.onResult: statusCode 0

I also tried the web page shown under https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android/master/receiver/receiver.html but got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly you have done. You mentioned: "The application with ID “MY APPLICATION ID” is not yet published under the Google Cast SDK Developer Console, nor has it been uploaded to the Google play Developer Console.". What do you mean by app id has not been uploaded to the developer console? If you created an app id, then it is there. One thing to check is that your certificate is a valid one (since your app is not published, you can switch to http for testing).

Comment: In the Google Cast SDK Developer Console I can set "Published" to "Yes" or "No". This is currently set to "No". I also did not upload the app to https://play.google.com/apps/publish (which is not necessary as far as I know). I bought my SSL certificate at https://www.strato.de. My Chrome browser accepts it.

Comment: You don't need to publish your app to get that working, nor you need to have app uploaded to play store. As for your certificate and whether that is causing an issue or not, as I suggested before, make it http to see if that solves the issue (hence narrowing down your issue) or not. I presume the "SOME_WEB_ADDRESS" that you have is resolvable externally (i.e. with Google's DNS). The desktop chrome has different settings for accepting certificates than Chromecast, it is a lot more forgiving that Chromecast.

Comment: Now it works with the https page! I am am able to cast text to the Chromecast device!
Thank you for your support!!!
I will delete my comment above as it shows http-addresses. The comment was:
I copied the html pages to SOME_HTML_PAGE (page I list above) and ANOTHER_HTML_PAGE (page from raw.githubusercontent.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android/…). Thus you could test them. My provider Strato (see strato.de) automatically forwards http requests pages to https (as I have a SSL certificate). Shall I (i) publish the application under cast.google.com/publish or should I (ii) move the pages to http?